# Apache Ignite Failed to complete exchange process

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Apache ignite .net client node fails to start with below error, any idea what could be the reason?

```
Exception : class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to complete exchange process. Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.CacheException

StackTrace:

at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.PlatformJniTarget.InStreamOutObject(Int32 type, Action`1 writeAction)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Ignite.GetOrCreateCache[TK,TV](CacheConfiguration configuration, NearCacheConfiguration nearConfiguration, PlatformCacheConfiguration platformCacheConfiguration, Op op)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Ignite.GetOrCreateCache[TK,TV](CacheConfiguration configuration, NearCacheConfiguration nearConfiguration, PlatformCacheConfiguration platformCacheConfiguration)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Ignite.GetOrCreateCache[TK,TV](CacheConfiguration configuration, NearCacheConfiguration nearConfiguration)
```

NOTE: I am trying to implement Read/Write through in Ignite .net 5.

Comment: Do you have a reproducer? Looks like an exception is thrown inside your CacheStore implementation.

Comment: Yes it always throwing the exception whenever I run the program.